# In OAuth2, when the refresh token request is executed to retrieve a new access token, are the previous Access Tokens invalidated?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Steps.

```
1. GET https://<canvas-install-url>/login/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://example.com/oauth_complete&state=YYY&scope=<value_1>%20<value_2>%20<value_n>
```

```
2. POST /login/oauth2/token [grant_type=authorization_code]
```

```
Response:
{
    "access_token": "1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "user": {"id":42, "name": "Jimi Hendrix"},
    "refresh_token": "tIh2YBWGiC0GgGRglT9Ylwv2MnTvy8csfGyfK2PqZmkFYYqYZ0wui4tzI7uBwnN2",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

```
3. POST /login/oauth2/token [grant_type=refresh_token]
```

```
Response:
{
    "access_token": "new_1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "user": {"id":42, "name": "Jimi Hendrix"},
    "refresh_token": "tIh2YBWGiC0GgGRglT9Ylwv2MnTvy8csfGyfK2PqZmkFYYqYZ0wui4tzI7uBwnN2",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

From step 2:

`"access_token": "1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg" - using this token returns an invalid access token error`

From step 3:

`"access_token": "new_1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg_new" - works!`

**My question is,**

1. Is this the expected behaviour?
   or
2. Should the access token from step 2 be valid until it expires(3600s)?

Answer (score 1):

No When you use the refresh token and refresh it will generate a new access token and attach to the refresh token. Old access tokens will no longer work after that.

Expires in is a maximum TTL of the access token after which refresh is compulsory but there is no minimum threshold for refreshing an access token.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Any chance you can point me to an OAuth2 guide that illustrates what you've mentioned? I've been unsuccessful in finding such documentation.

Comment: Does this mean or do you know whether, if you were to keep requesting **NEW** `access tokens` instead of using the `refresh tokens` route, are **ALL** access tokens that were issued valid till they expire? I'll test this but would be good to know what the community understands what does actually happen.

Answer (score 1):

(I wanted to respond to your comment in shazin's answer. But I have no reputation :( )

AFAIK The old access token is invalidated when the refresh token is used to get a new access token.

I briefly looked at the OAuth2 Spec but could not find anything saying that the old access token is invalidated when the refresh token is used. Perhaps because it is assumed the refresh token is only used when the access token is invalid.

Anyway perhaps these 2 references from the spec will help.

1. [Refresh token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5)
2. [Refreshing an Access Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-47)

Comment: Thank for the links much helpful, I'll post the same question to you - Does this mean or do you know whether, if you were to keep requesting **NEW** `access tokens` instead of using the `refresh tokens` route, are **ALL** access tokens that were issued valid till they expire? I'll test this but would be good to know what the community understands what does actually happen.